# Custom Google Analytics Session End Of Day

Tags: google-analytics, web-analytics

According to https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2731565?hl=en , a session in Google Analytics ends either after 30 minutes of user inactivity or at **midnight** of the time zone of the  GA profile. Unfortunately, the website I work on has its peak traffic around that time, and this means a large number of users will be double-counted towards the session total.

This may not be a huge deal since we use page load numbers more than session count, but still, it would be nice behavior to have the end-of-day trigger at the trough of user activity, closer to the early am hours. The only way I have seen of doing this is really disruptive (changing the time zone of the GA profile to the hour offset desired), is there a way to set the end-of-day time explicitly?

Answer (score 1):

Not an ideal solution, but you could set up a second view and change the Time Zone so that midnight occurs at an off-peak hour.

I'm not sure if this will fix data retroactively, but you would be able to benchmark the difference in session counts going forward.

More info: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1010249?hl=en